# Bypass a chat restriction as a mod discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have my bot events to clear the chat if someone sends a discord invite like this: https://dev.to/mikeywastaken/events-in-discord-py-mk0

```
filtered_words = ["test"]

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    for word in filtered_words:
        if word in msg.content:
            await msg.delete()
    if "discord.gg" in msg.content.lower():
      await msg.delete()
      await msg.channel.send("Do not advertise!")
```

But how can i make so that users with the kick member permission or administrator role can bypass the filter ? I want to send an invite as the owner and it gets deleted.

Comment: You can for example store all the usre IDs that have the permission in a list and check if the author is in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check their [guild permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.guild_permissions) or their [permissions in a channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.permissions_in).

These two will return a [discord.Permissions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions) object. With this you can use a condition to check the different permissions.

```py
if "discord.gg" in msg.content.lower() and not msg.author.guild_permissions.kick_members: #You can also do `permissions_in()`
    await msg.delete()
    await msg.channel.send("Do not advertise!")
```

FYI, I did not check for administrator permissions explicitly because `kick_members` is by default `True` if you are an administrator.